# How do I add a background image to a twitter bootstrap page with a table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table on my webpage and I want to add a background image. I still want the table to keep its white background, but around the table I want there to be a background image. If I just change the background image in the `<head>`, the white table's background changes to the image, which is not what I want.

Code:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-image: url('file:///....Images/background.JPG');  
  background-repeat:repeat;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;  
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;  
  border-radius: 6px;   
}
</style>
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

How do I do it the right way? BTW, I'm totally new to bootstrap/html/css, obviously?

Comment: Warning: your `file:///` URL will only work on your local machine.

Answer (score 2):

Think this way: before you set the background, every element is transparent. You're only setting the body background. What you need to do is, in the CSS, give your table a white background:

```
table {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have added `class="table"` to the table (if you haven't yet then you really should), Bootstrap gives it a transparent background by default. Add the background-color to it and it will work.